# Is $\det(I+aAVV^*A^*)$ increasing function in $a$.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is $$\det(I+aAVV^*A^*)$$ increasing function in $a$?

Here $A$, $V$ are complex matrices, $a$ is positive real value, $I$ is identity matrix and $^*$ defines conjugate transpose (Hermitian).

Thank you.

PS. NOT home work, related to my research work in information theory.

Comment: by "conjugate transform" you don't perchance mean *conjugate transpose*, i.e. Hermitian adjoint, do you?

Comment: @RobertLewis Thank you. Correct it, you are right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $X=AVV^*A^*$. Then $X$ is positive semi-definite. So its eigenvalues $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are all non-negative.

Then we have
$$
\det(I+aX)=\prod_{j=1}^n(1+ax_j).
$$
If $a<b$, then $1+ax_j<1+bx_j$, since $x_j\geq0$. The condition $a>0$ guarantees that all factors $1+ax_j$, $1+bx_j$ are positive. So
$$
\det(I+aX)=\prod_{j=1}^n(1+ax_j)\leq\prod_{j=1}^n(1+bx_j)=\det(I+bX).
$$

If we allow $a$ to be negative, the situation is more complicated, as different factors might have different signs.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain how $X$ is positive semi-definite?

Comment: A similar question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496496/detiaa-bbvvaa-bb-is-monotonic-in-a-b

Comment: @MLT: for any $x$, $x^*AVV^*A^*x=(x^*AV)(x^*AV)^*$